# Calculating total time duration in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a table data like this

```
(int)   (time)  [mySQL datatype]

Id     Duration 
------------------
1      00:10:00
2      10:10:00
3      03:00:00
4      04:13:00
```

i want to calculate the total duration from this table, how can we do it. like 17:33:00.
Could anybody please provide mysql query to calculate this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try converting to seconds, summing, then converting back to a time:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Duration)))
FROM Table1
```

Result:

```
17:33:00
```

Comment: but it is returning null in result

Comment: @A.P.S: That's probably becasue some of the durations are NULL. Add `WHERE Duration IS NOT NULL` after `FROM Table1` and it should fix the problem.

Comment: Hi Mark Byers, understand this is a legendary post. It'st just that we noticed if the Time format like hh:mm:ss values are summing up, it could result null when the values are more than 60 seconds, 60 minutes to consider as a minute+ or hour+ e.e. 02:45:30 + 01:38:40 = sum would be 03:84:10. Using CAST() the answer is returned as (null). Perhaps that's what A.P.S may have encountered. Yes it's good to avoid 'real' nulls from the calcualtion by adding the WHERE clause. So we gotta do the long formatting. [This is the bug description](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12108)

Comment: @bonCodigo: You are absolutely correct, thank you! I have updated the post.

Comment: Cheers. Coz yours is the first search result comes out for these types of questions :) [dummy ref](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7cd7/24).

Comment: **Warning**: [`TIME_TO_SEC()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) cuts off fractional seconds ([see MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html)). Therefore the total duration can be wrong if you use fractional seconds in `TIME(n)` (`n >= 1`).