# Counting hours using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm creating simple project where I count the employee attendance and other things
when employee late on work ,I have to enter the delay time, example
employee came to work late by 30 min, so I will enter on the field 30:00 or 00:30:00 ,  in the end of each month , week, or day, I want to calculate the time, such as 30 min + 1H + 25 min and in the end of each month I will get the total of all that hours and minutes on the report, the report will show me the average and the sum of that time.

the following fields ( Timing Logged in Duration , Total Talking Time, Work , Time Not ready Time ) I want to calculate the hours and minutes.

what I’m getting  in the report is showing the SUM of the hours I entered as time with AM/PM which is not what I’m looking for.

### this is MySQL query

```
SELECT
ID,
`Date`,
`Shift Time`,
`In charge`,
`Agent Name`,
Attendance,
Timing,
`Logged in Duration`,
`Total Talking Time`,
`Work Time`,
`Not ready Time`,
`Calls Handled`,
RNA,
`Shift Calls Presented`,
`Shift Calls Handled`,
`HD Calls Abandoned`,
`Upload Your Report`
FROM `shift report`
```

Comment: e.g. use SUM(Total Talking Time) with formatting. e.g. [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377832/calculating-total-time-duration-in-mysql) Next, you group by the employee. can you manage it?

Comment: It's probably easier to save the minutes as a Int field.  Makes calculations easier.

Comment: In anycase if you haven't managed the formatting, please do take a look this with [long formatting](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7cd7/4)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post you the answer in the perspective of summing up time value releated issues developers, users have face so far. It's not just about formatting.

You may or may not have noticed that there's posibility sum of your total time can be miscalculated by the engine. Further mysql engine could return null although you have values.

When you are adding/aggregating time values it is converted as a number and results will be in number format. If you attempt to adding up time values like the following:

e.g. 01:38:50, 03:40:25 --> should ideally result in 05:19:15

- If you do Sum(the above two) --> you get a number
- If you use CAST(Sum(the above two) AS TIME) --> you get null
- There are two other possibilities showed in the my code snippet.

[Sample code reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7cd7/24). It will show you the different results that we just discussed. As for now, it seems like three way formatting could help.

```
time_format(sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(logged_duration))),'%h:%i:%s') total_log_duration
```

[The bug reported to MySQL is not rectified yet.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12108)