# sum of a column after select from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to select a column from a table, not only display each row with its value but also display the total of the column according to the query.
As shown in the code provided below, each row is displayed perfectly, however, when comes to the total of the column, only the value of the first called row is displayed as a total.
Please look at the picture provided below. Only the first row selected with value of 25:18 is displayed as a total.
The expected total value at the bottom of the table should be 51:19+50:41+25:18, but the total again is just the first row (DESC). Please advise

[table display after selected from sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiWye.png)

```
if (($user != "") && ($date !="")){
    $mysql=("SELECT inet_ntoa(conv(hex(location_ip), 16, 10)) as ip, conv(hex(idvisitor), 16, 10) as visitorId, 
    visit_last_action_time, visit_first_action_time, visitor_localtime,  user_id, visit_total_time
    FROM piwik_log_visit WHERE user_id='".$user."' AND date(visit_first_action_time) ='".$date."'
    Order by visit_first_action_time DESC");}

$query= mysqli_query($conn, $mysql) or die ("SQL Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $time =date('F d, Y | h:i:s a', strtotime($row['visitor_localtime']));
            $time =date('h:i:s a', strtotime($row['visitor_localtime']));
            $idaction_url = $row['idaction_url'];
            $ip =$row['ip'];
            $visitor = $row['visitorId'];

            $first = date('F d, Y |', strtotime($row['visit_first_action_time']));
            $date = $first.' '.$time;

            ///total time added
            $sum = array($row['visit_total_time']);
            $sum_total = array_sum($sum);
            $sum_time = gmdate('H:i:s', $sum_total);    

            $total = gmdate('i:s', $row['total_time']);
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: can you share the complete code.

Comment: Check you answer Here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001718/sql-server-group-by-count-of-datetime-per-hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001718/sql-server-group-by-count-of-datetime-per-hour) OR
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402936/counting-hours-using-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402936/counting-hours-using-mysql)

Comment: @AsadRaza sorry but I have checked those answers yesterday, no help at all.....

Comment: @A.Kiyoshi edit your question and add complete code there don't add code in comment

Comment: you could simply do array_sum(array_column($row, 'visit_total_time')); If you dont want to make use of loop.

Comment: @B.Desai I just edit my question. Please advice....thank you for all the help

Comment: Thank you @SudhirBastakoti will make changes

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$sum_total = 0;
foreach($sum as $key=>$value)
{
   $sum_total+= $value;
}
echo $sum_total;
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the same results

Answer (score 0):

I got the total time to work through this code:

```
$sql=("SELECT SUM(total_visit_time) as total_time....);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

$total_time_spent += $row['total_time'];
}

echo $total_time_spent;
```