# Vuejs and laravel calculate hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have data in json from laravel backend which looks like: "03:30:00", "01:45:00", "00:15:00"
Is there an easy way to count them together in vuejs so its looks like this: "05:30:00"

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377832/calculating-total-time-duration-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is simple javascript.

If the time string is always going to look the same, you can do:

```
let times = ["03:30:00", "01:45:00", "00:15:00"]; // you can have an unlimited number of time strings
let hours = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let seconds = 0;
for (const i in times) {
    const time = times[i];
    let splitTime = (time + "").split(":"); // make sure it's a string
    seconds += parseInt(splitTime[2]);
    if(seconds > 59){ // make sure it only goes until 59
        minutes++;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
    }
    minutes += parseInt(splitTime[1]);
    if(minutes > 59){ // make sure it only goes until 59
        hours++;
        minutes = minutes % 60;
    }
    hours += parseInt(splitTime[0]);
}
let totalTime = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":"
            + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":"
            + (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds); // put the left side zeros
```

Comment: If I in vuejs return totalTime i Get 053100. It seems good, only one minute plus. How can I change let times to somethings like this: let times =  this.o2attendances.data.totaltime? this data.totaltime is json format from sql

Comment: if its a json array string, you can do JSON.parse(this.o2attendances.data.totaltime). If its an atual array, you can do just like you said

Comment: i corrected the answer. If you think its right, can you make it the correct answer?