# Eloquent Merge Queried rows from Model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 Models

**Models/Tasks**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'date',
    'workdone',
    'duration',
    'location',
];

public function Duty()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Duty::class, 'duty_id', 'id');
}

public function TaskType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TaskType::class, 'TaskType_id', 'id');
}
```

**Models/Duty**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'date',
        'vehicle_number',
        ...other fields
    ];

    public function Tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tasks::class);
    }
```

In my controller I am fetching all the tasks for the user like this

```
 $records = Tasks::all()
                ->with('TaskType')
                ->get();
```

**NOTE:**
*The date in Models/Tasks can vary for each task by +/- 1 day. eg. Two of three assigned tasks on duty day number 4 maybe recorded as 2022/4/22 and the third task assigned on the same day maybe recorded as the next day(2022/4/23). However all three tasks will belong to the Duty day number 4 have duty day number 4s id as their foreign key*

and all is well and this data is returned.

| Date | Duration | Work Done | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/12/04 | 00:30 | Hammering | Barn |
| 2021/12/04 | 01:15 | Ironing | Basement |
| 2021/12/04 | 00:15 | Jumping | Backyard |
| 2021/12/05 | 00:45 | Sweeping | Kitchen |
| 2021/12/05 | 00:35 | Weeding | Garden |

In a variation, I would like combine all the tasks in one day as follows using ORM. I'm new to eloquent and I have no idea how to approach it even. So the date column would have just the date once, Duration would be summed up and work done combined by commas and so on...

| Date | Duration | Work Done | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/12/04 | 02:00 | Hammering, Ironing, Jumping | Barn, Basement, Backyard |
| 2021/12/05 | 01:20 | Sweeping, Weeding | Kitchen, Garden |

Is this possible with Eloquent or should I take a recursive in PHP approach?
TIA

Comment: You need group by and group concat. Ref:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486296/how-to-use-group-concat-in-laravel and of course sum duration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377832/calculating-total-time-duration-in-mysql

Comment: Please tell me you aren't storing dates in the database as a string... Does your note mean you want them grouped by `duty_id` and not `date`?

Comment: No the dates are stored as `datetime` in the DB. I think thats what I want group by `duty_id`

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
$tasks = Tasks::with('TaskType')->get()->groupBy('date');

$final_arr = [];
foreach($tasks as $tk => $tv){
    $temp_arr = [];
    foreach($tv as $k => $v){
        if($k === 0){
            $temp_arr = [
                'date'      => $v->date,
                'duration'  => $v->duration,
                'work_done' => $v->work_done,
                'location'  => $v->location
            ];
        }else{
            $temp_arr['duration'] = date("H:i:s",strtotime($temp_arr['duration'])+strtotime($v->duration));
            $temp_arr['work_done'] .= ', '.$v->work_done;
            temp_arr['location'] .= ', '.$v->location;
        }
    }
    $final_arr[] = $temp_arr;
}
dd($final_arr);
```

I have not tested this code, but it should be something like this, hope it should give you an idea.

- You don't need to write `all()` when you are writing `get()` there
- `groupBy` will just group those data on `date` key so, all the data from same date will be inside same array. you can `dd($tv)` and you should see all those data from same date
- In case of first index `0`, it is just saving the data straight forward, on other case it is just adding value or concatenating value.